# How to reinstall macOS Sierra after formatting by Ubuntu

Tags: mac, macos, install, unix

I recently experienced a problem with my macOS Sierra that forced me to reinstall it. However the internet connection was bad, so I ended up installing Ubuntu 17 from USB instead.

I’ve now reformatted my hard disk and torrented a macOS Sierra installer. How can I burn it onto a USB stick?

Comment: Do you have the ability to get your hands on to another mac?

Comment: No unfortunately, not a lot of Mac users in my city

Comment: You only "burn" to optical media, e.g. _burn to DVD_. You "write" to a USB Flash Drive! Setting aside the illegalities of downloading a torrent of macOS, it's just not a good idea since you have no way of knowing if its been modified in a malicious manner. Go to an Apple store or acquire a copy of the macOS installer in a legitimate manner and write it to a USB Flash Drive, per Apple's instructions available at their website, boot your Mac with it, format the drive and install. Otherwise find a location you can reliably use Internet Recovery from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar situation with a friend of mine who installed a bad copy of Windows 7 onto their mac.

You can retry booting into **Internet Recovery Mode**. If a local recovery partition isn't found, which in your case it won't be due to the hard drive formatting, the Mac will try to recover the operating system over the internet. To force a Mac into internet recovery mode, hold **Option-Cmd-R** at startup. This process will take some time, and you will need to select a suitable Wi-Fi or other Internet connection once the computer has started up.

More information on macOS recovery can be found on [Apple's support site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Best of luck to you, and note it is probably ***not*** the best idea to install a pirated copy of macOS Sierra.

EDIT: 
As for "burning" things onto a USB stick, this [tool](https://etcher.io) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

great idea to download it from a torrent from piratebay.... **NOT** !!!

and I don't know, how to burn something on a USB stick...

but.... perhaps this may help you:

http://lpmv.epfl.ch/macosx

https://askubuntu.com/questions/620284/how-to-make-a-bootable-mac-usb-in-ubuntu

https://superuser.com/a/505832/401026

- when done: start Mac, press and hold "Alt" to get boot menu
- choose USB stick
- follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your hands onto another Mac, you can try the following (described also in this [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) article:

1. Download the macOS installer from the Mac App Store. Quit the installer if it opens automatically after downloading. The installer will be in your Applications folder.
2. Mount your USB flash drive or other volume. You could also use a secondary internal partition that has at least 12GB of available disk space for the installation files.
3. Open the Terminal app, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
4. Use the createinstallmedia command in Terminal to create the bootable installer. For detailed usage instructions, make sure that the appropriate macOS installer is in your Applications folder, then enter the following path in Terminal:

   /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia